# Xcode cannot find headers

Tags: c++, xcode, ogre

I am trying to build the OGRE sdk 1.9 on OS X 10.9 with Xcode 5.1.1. I downloaded the SDK from http://sourceforge.net/projects/ogre/files/ogre/1.9/1.9/OgreSDK_v1-9-0.dmg/download and have CMake 2.8-12 installed.

When I open the OGRE.xcodeproj and try to build it the compiler complains about this header missing...

[image: Xcode cannot find the header]

So I verified that the header actually is there

[image: Folder where header is located]

And then had a look at the header search paths. I don't know why some of these are showing NOTFOUND

[image: NOTFOUND showing in include directories]

I notice that Xcode by default puts (*) in "Subdirectories to exclude in recursive searches" so I removed it.

[image: (*) in Sub-directories to exclude in recursive searches]

I then added $SRCROOT -recursive to both header search paths and user header search paths

[image: Added $SRCROOT to user header search paths]

[image: Added $SRCROOT to header search paths]

But I am still getting that error when trying to compile. Does anyone know what is wrong here?

Comment: Open `project.pbxproj` in the text editor and replace every entry of `NOTFOUND` by `$SRCROOT/include/OGRE`, `project.pbxproj` is located in the project bundle `OGRE.xcodeproj`.

Comment: 06/2016 - still the same error - f***ing annoying. sigh.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to fix `NOT FOUND` issues by yourself according to the actual directory tree.
2. The `$SRCROOT/boost` cannot influenced by `recursive`. I think you can set `$SRCROOT/include/OGRE` as recursive and delete its sub directions. BTW, the default definition is `OGRE_SDK_ROOT`, you changed it?

Answer (score -1):

you can try this:

#include < ogre/ogreOverlaySystem.h >

(i am sure that it will work).

Comment: I am looking for a solution that will allow the headers to be found without modifying all of the includes in the program